# Find $\cos(x+y)$ and $\sin(x+y)$ given that $\cos x + \cos y = a$ and $\sin x + \sin y = b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\cos x + \cos y = a$ and $\sin x + \sin y = b$.
Find $\cos(x+y)$  and $\sin(x+y)$. 
I only need some hints to start as I am not able to get any way to go forward to.

Comment: Recall the angle sum formulas for sine and cosine.

Comment: @D.A.Robayo I know them but I am not able to get it in such a form that I can use the information given in the question

Comment: Remember that $\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$ and $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x$.

Comment: Hint: you have 4 equations instead of 2.

Comment: Waht happens if you take $a\cdot b$?

Comment: Thanks $a\cdot b$ was helpful @DiegoMath

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks I squared and added both the Equations and got cos(x-y)

Comment: Got all the answers Thanks to all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Let $u = \cos x + i \sin x$, $v = \cos y + i \sin y$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
u + v = a+ i b \\
\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = a -i b
\end{eqnarray}
so 
$$u v = (a+ib)/(a-ib)$$
But $uv = \cos(x+y) + i \sin(x+y)$. Now take real and imaginary parts.

Comment: $v=\cos{y}+i\sin{y}$?????

Comment: @ AsdrubalBeltran:  Yes, thanks!

Comment: neat! +1${}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a geometric way to find $\{(\cos x, \sin x), (\cos y, \sin y)\}$ and $(\cos(x+y), \sin(x+y))$.

The vector $(a,b)$ is a sum of two  vectors $(\cos x, \sin x)$, $(\cos y, \sin y)$ starting at the origin and ending on the unit circle therefore the points $(0,0)$, $(\cos x, \sin x)$,  $(\cos y, \sin y)$, $(a,b)$ are the vertices of a rhombus. Take the segment bisector of the diagonal $(0,0) (a,b)$ and find its intersections with the unit circle $(\cos x, \sin x)$ and $(\cos y, \sin y)$. To find the point $(\cos(x+y), \sin(x+y))$ draw the chord  through from $(1,0)$ perpendicular to the line $(0,0) (a,b)$ and take its other end.

A neat picture made by @Semiclassical $\ $--$\ $thanks!! $\ \ \ $  (using Chrome's Geogebra )

Reflect $(1,0)$ with respect to $(0,0) (a,b)$

[image]

blue: $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(a,b)$

Comment: [A picture speaks 1000 words](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bBxjh.png)

Comment: @Semiclassical: Classic! Can we add it &(credits $\mapsto$ you) ?

Comment: Certainly. FYI, I made it with Chrome's Geogebra app.

Comment: This is indeed very neat. But what is the purpose of the "segment bisector of the diagonal" which goes through $(\cos x, \, \sin x)$ and $(\cos y, \, \sin y)$? Your construction of the point $(\cos(x+y), \, \sin(x+y))$ does not need it.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Thanks!

Comment: @RoryDaulton:  
The solution also finds the pair $(\cos x,\sin x)$, $(\cos y,\sin y)$. These and the pair $(1,0)$, $(\cos(x+y),\sin(x+y))$ have the same  bisector $(0,0)$,$(a,b)$ so their products are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas

$$2\sin\frac{x+y}2\cos\frac{x-y}2=a$$

and $$2\cos\frac{x+y}2\cos\frac{x-y}2=b$$

Divide to find $\tan\dfrac{x+y}2$ assuming $ab\cos\dfrac{x-y}2\ne0$

Now apply [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)

---

Alternatively find $a^2+b^2,a^2-b^2,ab$ and use Prosthaphaeresis Formulas